# Why doesn't the pseudo traction force $T$ describe actual intensity?

Tags: continuum-mechanics, solid-mechanics

In **Nonlinear Solid Mechanics: A Continuum Approach for Engineering** book, Author *Gerhard A. Holzapfel*, chapter 3, section 1, page 111:

It is mentioned that the pseudo traction vector T (other names for it: first Piola-Kirchhoff/ nominal traction vector) , where $df = T dS$, doesn't describe the actual intensity.

Why is that?

[image]

Comment: What is "intensity" for the author?

Comment: He didn't specify. Could he mean intensity of force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point of the first Piola-Kirchhoff stress tensor is that it is a two-point stress. This mean that you are using information from two different vector spaces to define it. Here we are using the force from the deformed configuration and the area vector from the original (undeformed) configuration. In that sense, we can say that it is the generalization of the "engineering stress" defined for a uniaxial test.

According to this, and without having read the reference that you are using, I guess that the author uses "intensity" to refer to the magnitude of the traction vector. This vector won't be the same as the Cauchy traction vector. As a consequence, the components of both tensor will differ as well.